# I'm trying to do a Todo List App and when i pressed the add task its not adding below

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a createElement for the todo List and the appendchild but it's not adding to my website this is the code below

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("#add-todo-form");
  const input = document.querySelector("#new-todo-input");
  const listTask = document.querySelector('#todo-list');

  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const task = input.value;

    const todoList = document.createElement('div');
    todoList.classList.add('todo-item');

    const label = document.createElement('label');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    label.appendChild(input);
    label.appendChild(span);

    const todoContent = document.createElement('div');
    todoContent.classList.add('todo-content');

    todoList.appendChild(todoContent);

    const todoInput = document.createElement('input');
    todoInput.classList.add('text');
    todoInput.type = 'text'
    todoInput.value = task;
    todoInput.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');

    todoContent.appendChild(todoInput);

    const todoAction = document.createElement('div');
    todoAction.classList.add('action');

    const todoEdit = document.createElement('i');
    todoEdit.classList.add('bi-pencil-square');

    const todoDelete = document.createElement('i');
    todoDelete.classList.add('bi-trash3-fill');

    todoAction.appendChild(todoEdit);
    todoAction.appendChild(todoDelete);

    todoList.appendChild(todoAction);

    listTask.appendChild(todoList);

    input.value = '';

    todoEdit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if (todoEdit.innerText.toLowerCase() == 'bi-pencil-square') {
        todoInput.removeAttribute("readonly");
        todoInput.focus();
      } else {
        todoEdit.innerText = "bi-pencil-square";
        todoInput.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
      }
    });

    todoDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      listTask.removeChild(todoList)
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

:root {
  --Button: #432C7A;
  --Background: #FCE2DB;
  --font-color: #000;
  --alternative-font-color: #fff;
  --opacty: #998484;
  --error: #F83434;
  --check: #888;
  --margin: 0 1.8125rem;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.bubble {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  border: 2px solid var(--Button);
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
}

.bubble::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: var(--Button);
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked~.bubble::after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#name-greet:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]),
button {
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: initial;
}

.container,
.app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #4EB4FF 0%, rgba(24, 38, 48, 0) 100%);
}

.name {
  width: 265px;
  height: 262px;
  background-color: var(--Background);
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 278px;
  max-height: 455px;
  background-color: var(--Background);
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.name h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--font-color);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 72px;
}

#name {
  margin-top: 26px;
  width: 223px;
  height: 31px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding-left: 7px;
}

::placeholder {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: var(--opacty);
  opacity: 80%;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.name h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.greeting .title {
  display: flex;
}

.greeting .title input {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.greeting .title,
.greeting .title input {
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#name-greet::placeholder {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--opacty);
  opacity: 80%;
}

.greeting h1 {
  margin-left: 29px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.create-list h3 {
  margin-left: 1.8125rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.create-list h4 {
  margin: var(--margin);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: var(--opacty);
}

.create-list input[type=text] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 218px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  color: var(--font-color);
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 1.1rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
  ;
  border: 1px solid #847171;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0 1.8125rem 1rem;
}

.create-list input[type=submit] {
  margin: 0 1.8125rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 218px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: var(--alternative-font-color);
  background-color: var(--Button);
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
  ;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.create-list input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--Button);
  color: var(--font-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-list h3 {
  margin-left: 1.8125rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.todo-list .list {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.todo-list .todo-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--alternative-font-color);
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 14px 28px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 10px 10px;
  margin: var(--margin);
  max-width: 234px;
}

.todo-item label {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-item .todo-content {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.todo-item .todo-content input {
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px 10px -15px;
  border: none;
}

.todo-item .action {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo-item .action i {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
}

.todo-item .action .bi-pencil-square {
  color: var(--Button);
}

.todo-item .action .bi-trash3-fill {
  color: var(--error);
}

.todo-item.done .todo-content input {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: var(--grey);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .name {
    width: 543px;
    height: 376px;
  }
  .name h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  #name {
    width: 418px;
    height: 54px;
    margin-left: 63px;
  }
   ::placeholder {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .name #loading {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .box {
    max-width: 543px;
    max-height: 600px;
  }
  .greeting .title,
  .greeting .title input {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  #name-greet::placeholder {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: var(--opacty);
    opacity: 80%;
  }
  .create-list h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .create-list h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .create-list input[type=text] {
    max-width: 468px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .create-list input[type=submit] {
    max-width: 468px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .todo-list h3 {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  .todo-list .todo-item {
    max-width: 468px;
  }
  .todo-item .action .bi-pencil-square {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .todo-item .action .bi-trash3-fill {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .todo-item .todo-content input {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px -15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-------Links------->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!--JS Import-->
  <title>Todo-List App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--App Container-->
  <main class="app">

    <!--Box for the List-->
    <div class="box">

      <!--Header of the App-->
      <section class="greeting">
        <h1 class="title" id="greet">Hello! <input type="text" id="name-greet" placeholder="Name here" />
        </h1>
      </section>

      <!--Add task-->
      <section class="create-list">
        <h3>Create a Todo</h3>

        <form id="add-todo-form">
          <h4>What's on your todo?</h4>
          <input type="text" name="new-todo-input" id="new-todo-input" placeholder="e.g Practice Coding">

          <input type="submit" id="task-submit" value="Add Todo">
        </form>
      </section>

      <!--Todo List-->
      <section class="todo-list">
        <h3>Todo List</h3>
        <div class="list" id="todo-list">
          <!--<div class="todo-item">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <span class="bubble"></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="todo-content">
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                class="text" 
                                value="A new task"
                                readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="action">
                            <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
                            <i class="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i>
                        </div>-->
        </div>

      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I've tried using the `appendchild` for a simple button and then a word will appear but when I applied the code to the todo list the task I input its not adding the list and I'm achieving this type of todo list in the youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkESyVB4oUw&t=6s

Comment: Have you noticed the error i n the console about `input` being used before being initialized?

Comment: I think there may be a muddle on the scope of the const input. You define it to begin with, but when you are using it in the event listener are you clear which one you mean as you then define another one locally. Are you using your browser devtools inspect facility to see if there are any errors on the console?

Answer (score 0):

just change your form event listener two lines as i marked

> ```
> // changed below two lines
> const textbox = document.querySelector("#new-todo-input");
> const task = textbox.value;
> ```

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const form = document.querySelector("#add-todo-form");
  const input = document.querySelector("#new-todo-input");
  const listTask = document.querySelector('#todo-list');

  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // changed below two lines
    const textbox = document.querySelector("#new-todo-input");
    const task = textbox.value;

    const todoList = document.createElement('div');
    todoList.classList.add('todo-item');

    const label = document.createElement('label');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    label.appendChild(input);
    label.appendChild(span);

    const todoContent = document.createElement('div');
    todoContent.classList.add('todo-content');

    todoList.appendChild(todoContent);

    const todoInput = document.createElement('input');
    todoInput.classList.add('text');
    todoInput.type = 'text'
    todoInput.value = task;
    todoInput.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');

    todoContent.appendChild(todoInput);

    const todoAction = document.createElement('div');
    todoAction.classList.add('action');

    const todoEdit = document.createElement('i');
    todoEdit.classList.add('bi-pencil-square');

    const todoDelete = document.createElement('i');
    todoDelete.classList.add('bi-trash3-fill');

    todoAction.appendChild(todoEdit);
    todoAction.appendChild(todoDelete);

    todoList.appendChild(todoAction);

    listTask.appendChild(todoList);

    input.value = '';

    todoEdit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if (todoEdit.innerText.toLowerCase() == 'bi-pencil-square') {
        todoInput.removeAttribute("readonly");
        todoInput.focus();
      } else {
        todoEdit.innerText = "bi-pencil-square";
        todoInput.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
      }
    });

    todoDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      listTask.removeChild(todoList)
    });
  });
});




<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: null -->
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

:root {
  --Button: #432C7A;
  --Background: #FCE2DB;
  --font-color: #000;
  --alternative-font-color: #fff;
  --opacty: #998484;
  --error: #F83434;
  --check: #888;
  --margin: 0 1.8125rem;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

.bubble {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  border: 2px solid var(--Button);
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
}

.bubble::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background-color: var(--Button);
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
  border-radius: 999px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked~.bubble::after {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#name-greet:not([type="radio"]):not([type="checkbox"]),
button {
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: initial;
}

.container,
.app {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #4EB4FF 0%, rgba(24, 38, 48, 0) 100%);
}

.name {
  width: 265px;
  height: 262px;
  background-color: var(--Background);
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 278px;
  max-height: 455px;
  background-color: var(--Background);
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.name h1 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--font-color);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 72px;
}

#name {
  margin-top: 26px;
  width: 223px;
  height: 31px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: transparent;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding-left: 7px;
}

::placeholder {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: var(--opacty);
  opacity: 80%;
}

input:focus::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

.name h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.greeting .title {
  display: flex;
}

.greeting .title input {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  min-width: 0;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.greeting .title,
.greeting .title input {
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#name-greet::placeholder {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: var(--opacty);
  opacity: 80%;
}

.greeting h1 {
  margin-left: 29px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.create-list h3 {
  margin-left: 1.8125rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.create-list h4 {
  margin: var(--margin);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: var(--opacty);
}

.create-list input[type=text] {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 218px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 0.8rem;
  color: var(--font-color);
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 1.1rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
  ;
  border: 1px solid #847171;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0 1.8125rem 1rem;
}

.create-list input[type=submit] {
  margin: 0 1.8125rem 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 218px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: var(--alternative-font-color);
  background-color: var(--Button);
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
  ;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.create-list input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--Button);
  color: var(--font-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-list h3 {
  margin-left: 1.8125rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.todo-list .list {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.todo-list .todo-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--alternative-font-color);
  padding: 0.8rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 14px 28px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 10px 10px;
  margin: var(--margin);
  max-width: 234px;
}

.todo-item label {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.todo-item .todo-content {
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.todo-item .todo-content input {
  color: var(--font-color);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 5px 10px -15px;
  border: none;
}

.todo-item .action {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.todo-item .action i {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  right: 25px;
}

.todo-item .action .bi-pencil-square {
  color: var(--Button);
}

.todo-item .action .bi-trash3-fill {
  color: var(--error);
}

.todo-item.done .todo-content input {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: var(--grey);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .name {
    width: 543px;
    height: 376px;
  }
  .name h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  #name {
    width: 418px;
    height: 54px;
    margin-left: 63px;
  }
   ::placeholder {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .name #loading {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .box {
    max-width: 543px;
    max-height: 600px;
  }
  .greeting .title,
  .greeting .title input {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  #name-greet::placeholder {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: var(--opacty);
    opacity: 80%;
  }
  .create-list h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .create-list h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .create-list input[type=text] {
    max-width: 468px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .create-list input[type=submit] {
    max-width: 468px;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .todo-list h3 {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
  .todo-list .todo-item {
    max-width: 468px;
  }
  .todo-item .action .bi-pencil-square {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .todo-item .action .bi-trash3-fill {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .todo-item .todo-content input {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px -15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-------Links------->
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!--JS Import-->
  <title>Todo-List App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--App Container-->
  <main class="app">

    <!--Box for the List-->
    <div class="box">

      <!--Header of the App-->
      <section class="greeting">
        <h1 class="title" id="greet">Hello! <input type="text" id="name-greet" placeholder="Name here" />
        </h1>
      </section>

      <!--Add task-->
      <section class="create-list">
        <h3>Create a Todo</h3>

        <form id="add-todo-form">
          <h4>What's on your todo?</h4>
          <input type="text" name="new-todo-input" id="new-todo-input" placeholder="e.g Practice Coding">

          <input type="submit" id="task-submit" value="Add Todo">
        </form>
      </section>

      <!--Todo List-->
      <section class="todo-list">
        <h3>Todo List</h3>
        <div class="list" id="todo-list">
          <!--<div class="todo-item">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox">
                            <span class="bubble"></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="todo-content">
                            <input 
                                type="text" 
                                class="text" 
                                value="A new task"
                                readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="action">
                            <i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i>
                            <i class="bi bi-trash3-fill"></i>
                        </div>-->
        </div>

      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```